# upgrade to rails 3 AND acts_as_authenticated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication

Hi I am trying to upgrade an application to rails 3 that was written in Rails 2.3.5 
one of the biggest challenge I am facing is plug-in acts_as_authenticated.

I would like to know if there is a tutorial or steps to migrate from acts_as_authenticated to a simple custom authentication.

My application requires very basic authentication.. 
I saw railscast on writing authentication from scratch that was not helpful

the biggest challenge is current_user method written by the plug-in. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3):

The plugin acts_as_authenticated is now depreciated and has been replaced with [restful-authentication](http://github.com/technoweenie/restful-authentication/tree/master).

You should install this plugin instead, or use a new plugin like [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise).

Both of these contain current_user methods in the same way that you are used to.

The only difference between the acts_as_authenticated and restful-authentication tables is that the later has a name column. If your database already has one of these, then you need to change nothing. Otherwise add a migration with:

```
add_column :users, :name, :string, :limit => 100, :default => '', :null => true
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion. Its great to learn that Current_user method is exactly supported. I believe installing restfull-authentication would require changing the users table and database schema.  Is there any other option.. Thanks

Comment: Here are the two migrations. http://bit.ly/Mqz3P3 vs http://bit.ly/Mqz6L0 - I have updated my answer with what you need to change. Hopefully now it is complete and you can mark it as accepted :)

Comment: You should also take a look at "[has_secure_password](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/ClassMethods/has_secure_password)" which is built in - in many cases you won't need a third party gem for authentication. See this RailsCast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/270-authentication-in-rails-3-1

Comment: The current_user method is just a tiny method in your ApplicationController, something like `def current_user @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id].present? end`